# Blender Physic. Can an active rigid Body Object follow an empty or s.e

Tags: physics

I like to use a plane/cube or s.e. set as active rigid body that should interact with a passive body plane (ground) an follow a given path or follow f.e. an keyframed empty.

For better imagination, i like to simulate the behavior of a sled which is pulled by a f.e. a human. The x,y movement is given by keyframes an i like to simulate the z location an the rotation of the object.